# Not able to delete an entity that extends another using DiscriminatorColumn due to foreign key constraint

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED") on my User class and i’ve created an Agent class which extends User

When I try to delete the Agent entry or the corresponding User entr, I get a foreign key constraint error

How can I add orphan removal?

This are my User class entity settings:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"agent" = "Agent", "user" = "User"})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
```

Comment: Hi, on the documentation (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance), you can see a notice that says : ```When you do not use the SchemaTool to generate the required SQL you should know that deleting a class table inheritance makes use of the foreign key property ON DELETE CASCADE in all database implementations. A failure to implement this yourself will lead to dead rows in the database.```
Did you add the ON DELETE CASCADE or use a tools that automatically add it ?

Comment: @Caucorico There is no place to add 'ON DELETE CASCADE' that I can see. None of the PHPBlock properties - '@ORM\DiscriminatorColumn', '@ORM\DiscriminatorColumn' or '@ORM\DiscriminatorMap' support adding that

My problem would be solved if I could find a place to add 'ON DELETE CASCADE'

Comment: It is not in the code that we add the `ON DELETE CASCADE` but in the database.
When you create the foreign key in your table Agent, you can add `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: @Caucorico Is there a way to script it? It seems strange that I would need to manually connect to my DB for each instance and make that setting

Doctrine, as an ORM, should be able to handle that for me somehow

Comment: I think ```doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql``` will do if you use this tool to generate your database.
Try with only --dump-sql if you want to check that the ON DELETE CASACDE is added before update the database schema

Answer (score 0):

It seems a "hacky" solution but i've added this code to my delete agent controller code:

```
$user = $this->userRepository->find($agent->getId());

$this->entityManager->remove($user);
$this->entityManager->remove($agent);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```